# How to have a button associated with div for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I currently have and HTML page that receives data about a group of people from a Flask script as so.

```
return render_template('test.html', data = response)
```

I can currently get all the data to correct print on the page, but what I want to do is make a button that toggles the information. For example the fields in the listed in the HTML below are name, age, height, and weight; What I want do is make the name a button that toggles the age, height, and weight for that particular person. In my current implementation I have implemented a button, however it toggles the information for all the people that are displayed on the page rather than the individuals whose name I clicked on.

So my question to you guys out there is if there is any way to get a button to associate with a particular div to toggle?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>A Title</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").click(function(){
                    $("div").toggle();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        {% for item in data.Items %}
        <button>Person Name:   {{ item.name }}</button><br>
        <div>
            Age:   {{ item.age }}<br>
            Height:   {{ item.height }}<br>
            Weight:   {{ item.weight }}<br>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        {% endfor %}

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this but this'll work without setting identifiers for every row. If you use this method, make sure to remove the onclick event action that you have in your header now.

```
{% for item in data.Items %}
    <button onclick="$(this).siblings('div.extrainfo').toggle();">Person Name:   {{ item.name }}</button><br>
    <div class="extrainfo">
        Age:   {{ item.age }}<br>
        Height:   {{ item.height }}<br>
        Weight:   {{ item.weight }}<br>
    </div>
    <br><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Furthermore, if you want the extra info to be hidden by default, add this in your stylesheet:

```
.extrainfo {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for giving me the solution to my troubles. I am just started to learn about the world of HTML and I will be definitely be looking into your solution to break it down and figure out how it works. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry to a be a bother again, but this is performing the same as before, where a single button would toggle all of the data regardless of name. Do you  think I am missing anything?

Comment: Happy to help. Make sure to read up on how jquery and javascript in general works. Also, remember to set unique identifiers for your elements using id or class values for different elements (e.g.: id="button1" for your button and id="div1" for you extra info div), otherwise when you do $('button') or $('div'), you're adding an event listener to every button and every div on the page. Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

Create a event handler for the div in question. You want it to visually hide itself when toggled, right? You would set this visible property to false. I think you should have a "hide this" button or checkbox for each person, and have it toggle the visibility for that person's information. I would also suggest looking at the "this" keyword in javascript and how it works because I assume you have a dynamic number of people, and you're not assigning a unique id to each of them?

Comment: Yeah I do have a lot to learn, as I am just jumping into javascript for fun. You are right that there is going to be a dynamic number of people. I will be looking into "this". Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Glad it helped. I think Sage gave an answer using the jquery toggle() as well as "this". Definitely a good place to start.